# Which has better compatibility with ubuntu - xps 13 / xps 14?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, laptop, dell, compatibility

I am planning on buying a dell XPS 13 or XPS 14.. but really confused in choosing one..

- Will be installing Ubuntu along side windows (dual boot)
- Main purpose - web & mobile app development

It seems XPS 13 ( only pre-installed Ubuntu - project sputnik) is Ubuntu certified and XPS 14 is not.

Which one, out of the 2 laptops has better Ubuntu compatibility and most apt for web development?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

XPS 13 / XPS 15! I can´t finde a XPS 14? :-)

I have the XPS 13 (9350) and it works fine without problems. After the XPS 13 arrived me, the first thing what I do. I re-installed the Ubuntu - Version (no upgrade). Now my XPS 13 runs with Ubuntu 16.04. and I can´t find issus.

The biggest problem for me is the "ubuntu software". It makes me crazy. 
But with Synaptic i can work without the "new" "ubuntu software".

Back to your question. I think the XPS 13 and the 15 works both fine with Ubuntu and i think there would be working better in the future... in a few month.

I have the low price version of the XPS 13, without touch and iris-hd.

Answer (score 0):

Since the xps 13 is preloaded with ubuntu and all hardware parts are working, I think the 13" model has the best compatibility today. The 13" is enough for web dev and has a 1080p Full HD Display.

I would recommend that you have an external (second) display for graphics work.

But Dell seems to have more models in work: 
http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/os-applications/f/4613/t/19494844.aspx

And I think to wait for haswell upgrade isnt bad at all.